# Nautilus crashes when using "New folder with selection" since 15.10 update

Tags: nautilus

Since I updated my 15.04 to 15.10 my Nautilus keeps crashing, when I use "New folder with selection" with more than about five files (don't know the exact number but it's less than 10). When I start Nautilus via terminal I get the following error:

```
ERROR:nautilus-view.c:1834:rename_newly_added_folder: code should not be reached
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I didn't have this problem with 15.04.